# Can parse_url ever detect a malformed URL when combined with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, url

Consider the following code that liberally tries to detect possible URLs (anything that looks vaguely like a domain name due to combined dots and character) and tries to parse it:

```
if ( preg_match( '/[a-z\.0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i', $text, $possibleUrl ) ) {
    $urlResult = parse_url( 'http://' . $possibleUrl[0] );
    echo $urlResult === false ? 'malformed URL' : 'parseable URL';
}
```

Is it possible to give that code a input value for `$text`  that will produce the output `malformed URL`?

Comment: `parse_url` is a parser,  not a validator. `$text = 'it.is not a url in any way';` still results with "parseable URL". Validator is something like this: https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/Constraints/UrlValidator.php

Comment: Im' not trying to validate, just to detect. Thanks to the anser to this question, I'll probably drop the call to `parse_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: No.

Long answer: `parse_url` (see in the C source code of php: ext/standard/url.c `php_url_parse_ex()` function) does not check validity of any input between the scheme (i.e. `http://` here) and a subsequent `@`, `:` or `/`; it just assumes it's the host part. [Note: for the `@`, it considers the part *after* it the host.]

Your regex only allows characters `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`, thus it will be recognized as host part in any case.